# Confusion about counter variable at loop termination

Tags: java, for-loop

For this snippet of code:

```
int number = 25;
int i;

boolean isPrime = true;
for (i = 2; i < number && isPrime; i++) {
  if (number % i == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
  }
}

System.out.println("i is " + i + " isPrime is " + isPrime);
```

I was under the impression that the output would be: `"i is 5 isPrime is false"`, since when `i=5`, `number % i == 0` is `true`, thus the variable `isPrime` becomes `false` and the loop won't continue.

So when the loop returns to

```
for (i = 2; i < number && isPrime; i++)
```

it wouldn't increment `i`, since the condition is no longer valid (`i < number && isPrime`). What's going on?

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: The `i++` is applied before the conditional check.

Comment: "i is 6 isPrime is false"

Comment: Ah I see, so the order in which the for loop is constructed, is not necessarily the way order in which it operates.

Comment: I could use break; to make it quit at i=5, I believe

Comment: Do you mean that the counter should be declared and initialised inside the brackets? Yes, I agree. Though the question had written it out like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you understand the concept of a loop the wrong way. A `for` loop with the structure:

```
for(init; cond; inc) {
    body
}
```

works as follows:

1. First the `init` is executed;
2. Next the condition is evaluated, if the condition is `true`, goto 3, otherwise, end loop.
3. The `body` is executed
4. The `inc` is executed (regardless whether the condition holds);
5. goto 2.

As is specified, the increment (for your example `i++` will **always be called after executing the `body`**, **regardless whether the condition holds**. You could therefore rewrite the above `for` loop as:

```
for(init; cond;) {
    body;
    inc
}
```

(so with an empty increment at the `for` header). Here a compiler has no means to disambiguate between `body` and `inc`. The syntax of the `for` loop is structured that way such that programmers would not forget *to perform an increment*, a typical error that occurs often with `while` loops.

Comment: That makes sense now. I thought that the increment only occurred if the condition held. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 3):

If you loop was to stop on `i < number` it would have to `i++` first.

The loop doesn't know that you will be stopping on `isPrime` instead and "know" to not bother incrementing.

What you should do is drop the flag as it would be simpler.

```
int number = 25;

for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
  if (number % i == 0) {
     System.out.println("i is " + i + " " + number + " is not prime");
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen someone writing for-loops like this. Try it by using the `break` keyword instead:

```
int number = 25;
boolean isPrime = true;

for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
      isPrime = false;
      break;
  }
}

System.out.println("i is " + i + " isPrime is " + isPrime);
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Furthermore although the OP's way to perform a `break` is not exceptionally popular, it is a correct way to do it.